# Get a random sample from dataframe with grouped columns?

Tags: pandas, numpy, dataframe, time-series, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe of time series data, called `dates_c` that looks like this:

```
       DATE_T               Da             HN      NAR     TJH
0      2014-01-01 00:11:25  2014-01-01     3520    11931   769.198   
1      2014-01-01 00:11:25  2014-01-01     3560    11942   338.143   
2      2014-01-01 00:11:25  2014-01-01     3542    11937   665.481   
3      2014-01-01 00:11:25  2014-01-01     3563    11944   529.058   
4      2014-01-01 00:11:25  2014-01-01     3535    11936  2883.945
```

I want to get 60 random rows per Da + NAR. This is what I did:

```
np.random.seed(987)
columns = ['DATE_T', 'HN', 'TJH']
new = dates_c.groupby(['Da', 'NAR'])[columns].apply(pd.Series.sample, n=60, replace=False).reset_index()
```

I keep getting this error:

```
ValueError: Key 2014-01-01 00:00:00 not in level Index([2014-01-01, 2014-01-02, 2014-01-03, 2014-01-04, 2014-01-05, 2014-01-06,
       2014-01-07, 2014-01-08, 2014-01-09, 2014-01-10,
       ...
       2014-12-22, 2014-12-23, 2014-12-24, 2014-12-25, 2014-12-26, 2014-12-27,
       2014-12-28, 2014-12-29, 2014-12-30, 2014-12-31],
      dtype='object', name='Date', length=320)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you need `replace = True` since some group may do not have enough data point for n=60

```
out = df.groupby(['Date', 'NOAA_AR']).apply(lambda x : x.sample(n=60,replace=True))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
dates_count.groupby(['Date', 'NOAA_AR'])[COLS].sample(60).reset_index()
```